# Command Button to modify cell value in unknown name open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So the issue I'm having is we have a schedule program made via excel, that is set to replace all user names and shift times with "####" and where it would normally display names inputs "Contact blah blah for new version." This occured on 1/1/15. For now they can backdate their computer to a date prior to 1/1/15 and once they type a value in to any cell the worksheet runs and all their data re-appears. We have locations across the country that saves the file every two weeks to Wildcardname.xls  I'm looking for a way to program a command button that finds the other random name opened workbook, goes to hidden sheet "help" and changes the value of Cell A184 to "01/01/2016" or any date I plug in. Which would remove the "####" issue and replace it with the originally inputed values. The user could then save the file and carry on.

I was browsing through various help boards and found this..prompts a user to select the workbook. This would be the workbook that needs changed.

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/695467-copy-values-from-a-worksheet-to-another-workbook-source-workbook-name-unknown.html

```
Sub CopyData()

  Dim DstRng As Range
  Dim DstWkb As Workbook
  Dim DstWks As Worksheet
  Dim FileFilter As String
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim SrcRng As Range
  Dim SrcWkb As Workbook
  Dim SrcWks As Worksheet
  Dim SheetName As String

    SheetName = "Output Table"

    FileFilter = "Excel Workbooks (*.xls), *.xls"
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter, , "Open Source Workbook")

    If Filename = "False" Then
       MsgBox "Open Source File Canceled."
       Exit Sub
    End If

      Set SrcWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
      Set SrcWks = SrcWkb.Worksheets(SheetName)
      Set SrcRng = SrcWks.Range("A2:H20")

    FileFilter = "Excel Workbooks (*.xls), *.xls"
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter, , "Open Destination Workbook")

    If Filename = "False" Then
       MsgBox "Open Destination File Canceled."
       Exit Sub
    End If

      Set DstWkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
      Set DstWks = DstWkb.Worksheets(SheetName)
      Set DstRng = DstWks.Range("A2:H20")

      SrcRng.Copy Destination:=DstRng

End Sub
```

Can this be modified to accomplish what I want to complete?

I can't post an image yet, so here's a link to a mock up.  Before shot of the program on the left, and on the right is what I want it to look like.

http://i528.photobucket.com/albums/dd330/DLN1223/mockup.jpg

Hopefully this description makes since....

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: change the program that creates the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim WKbook as workbook
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Select Workbook to Open")
If FileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub    'quit on cancel
Set Wkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, False, False)
```

With this, I can the set the value I want, and save changes

```
Wkbook.Sheets("help").Range("A184")=#1/1/2016#
Wkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

depending on the filetype, you may need to change `Excel files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx` to `Excel files (*.xls),*.xls`

Comment: When I run that I get a run time error '424' Object required.   Is that because the "Help" worksheet is hidden?

Comment: fixed typo - I was working on a monthly workbook I have, and forgot to remove those specific references to a more generic one. vba can even find xlVeryHidden worksheets, so visibility is not a issue